# Can I input in arrayList similar to array?

Tags: java

```java
public void getDisMarks()
   {
       marks=new int[3];
       System.out.print("Enter marks of Physics: ");
       marks[0]=sc.nextInt();
       System.out.print("Enter marks of Chemistry: ");
       marks[1]=sc.nextInt();
       System.out.print("Enter marks of Maths: ");
       marks[2]=sc.nextInt();
}
```

So in this piece of code we are using array for 3 definite subjects. And we're using scanner class to input from the user. Let's say in the future I want to add a couple of more subject. So coding it again would not make it any flexible.

So I read that we could use arrayList, How can I use scanner class with arrayList similar to this piece of code.

Comment: hello and welcome to SO. Before asking a question about such generic functionality please take a second and google the thing you are asking, like `java arraylist`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("How many marks to enter?");
        int marksToEnter = sc.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < marksToEnter; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter next mark");
            list.add(sc.nextInt());
        }
        System.out.println(list);
    }
```